# Protocol Violation - Verb does not allow content type

Tags: wcf, http, servicebus

Update: I was at Build 2013, and [Mark Simms](http://www.linkedin.com/pub/mark-simms/6/8a6/7b6) looked at this and confirmed that HTTP request leaving the router does have a "Body" in the request.  He felt that this was caused by the Get arriving at the SB, then packaged to be routed, then the package is managed again as a Messsage type, before sending it back out again.  In between the packaging and routing, properties are left in the body of the request - which violates protocol for the "GET".  All this however lives within MS framework either in the .NET, or in the ServiceBus.  As the body is immutable (at least I can't find a way to alter it), the only means is to duplicate the request, and then update the original request on the way out.

This is a small part of a routing application that takes in a HTTP GET/POST request from a Azure ServiceBus endpoint, brings it down via the relay channel to my local workstation, where I rewrite the URL, and send it to my local web service.

Here is the interface - generic so that it can receive any type of call to a controller/action URL

```
  // The Router, and general concept of how to recieve from the SB and redirect was taken from
  // Tony Sneed Blog - which he documented here: http://blog.tonysneed.com/2012/04/24/roll-your-own-rest-ful-wcf-router/
  //
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "urn:Twiddler")]
    public interface IRoutingService
    {
        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "")]
        [OperationContract(AsyncPattern = true, Action = "*", ReplyAction = "*")]
        IAsyncResult BeginProcessRequest(Message requestMessage, AsyncCallback asyncCallback, object asyncState);

        Message EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult);
    }
}
```

Here is the code:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall,
     AddressFilterMode = AddressFilterMode.Any, ValidateMustUnderstand = false)]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class RoutingService : IRoutingService, IDisposable
{
  private IRoutingService _client;

  /// <summary>
  /// when a message is received from the SB, it arrives here as simply a message - 
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="requestMessage"></param>
  /// <param name="asyncCallback"></param>
  /// <param name="asyncState"></param>
  /// <returns></returns>
  public IAsyncResult BeginProcessRequest(Message requestMessage, AsyncCallback asyncCallback, object asyncState)
  {
    string RequestMessageAction = requestMessage.Headers.Action;

    IAsyncResult asyncResult = null;


    //if the full URI for the namespace does not match the one contructed in Twiddler, then pass it through - we have nothing to do with it!
    if (requestMessage.Headers.To.AbsoluteUri.Contains(Utilities.ServiceFormBridge.NameSpaceName) && requestMessage.Headers.To.AbsoluteUri.Contains(Utilities.ServiceFormBridge.EndPointName) == false)
      return asyncResult;

    //as the service bus will accept anything in terms of controllers and actions, we only need alter the DestinationAddress.Authority (host and port)
    var RewriteTheURL = requestMessage.Headers.To.AbsoluteUri.Replace(string.Format("http://{0}.servicebus.windows.net/{1}/", ServiceFormBridge.NameSpaceName, ServiceFormBridge.EndPointName), ServiceFormBridge.DestinationWebSite);

    Uri DestinationAddress = new Uri(RewriteTheURL);

    System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory<IRoutingService> factory = null;

    factory = new ChannelFactory<IRoutingService>(new WebHttpBinding(), DestinationAddress.AbsoluteUri);

    WebHeaderCollection httpHeaders = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers;
    httpHeaders.Remove("Host");
    httpHeaders.Add("Host", DestinationAddress.Authority); //give it the new host that we are re-directing to

    httpHeaders.Remove("Connection");  //todo: not sure I need this, but without it there is an exception between Keep-Alive and Closed

    // Set factory and message address
    factory.Endpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress(DestinationAddress);
    requestMessage.Headers.To = DestinationAddress;


    _client = factory.CreateChannel();

    asyncResult = _client.BeginProcessRequest(requestMessage, asyncCallback, asyncState);

    return asyncResult;
  }
}
```

On the BeginProcessRequest, I get an exception:
Protocol Violation: Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type

Which I have researched and I understand that under a GET request, there can't be anything in the body of the request.

As my code works for a POST, I can only assume that for some reason, there is something in the body.

However, as the originating request was a GET from a browser using the URL of the ServiceBus, I'm not sure why there would be anything in the body.

So:

1. I'm thinking I'm doing something in the code that is causing me a problem - if so I would like to know what!
2. If there is something in the incoming request, how can I remove it so I don't get the violation?
3. Any other suggestions, improvements to the code?

Comment: So... the interface only specifies WebInvoke, and not WebGet... so why does it then allow a GET request to be relayed into the service? Using such a generic interface, do I have to handle GET and POST's differently?  I'm not touching the request body in either case...

Comment: The reason why GET requests get relayed is because the Action and ReplyAction both specify "*", which means that all messages are sent here.  Having a WebInvoke attribute on this interface is then point less!

Answer (score 0):

Placing this attribute on the operation, [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "")], supports POST by default, but you can pass a parameter specifying other verbs, such as PUT, DELETE, etc.  However, GET is supported by a different attribute, [WebGet].  I would suggest adding additional operations to the router, one with WebGet, and others with WebInvoke and different HTTP verbs.

Comment: So why does the get request get into the method? Should it not simply drop at the endpoint?

Comment: Also, as this is simply passing on the request, why the error? Content type is null, action is GET so why the violation?

Comment: Tony - see my comment above - WebInvoke/WebGet are pointless here because Action, and ReplyAction are both set to "*", and the return type is Message.  That means ALL messages are routed to this interface.

Comment: Remember this is WCF. :) Service operations only support POST, unless you specify differently using WebInvoke (plus verb for non-POST such as PUT, MERGE, DELETE, etc) or WebGet. Stepping back, however, WCF is probably not the right choice for a truly REST-based routing mechanism. Sort of like Apples and Oranges, because for REST the URL is looked at differently.  I would recommend using ASP.NET Web API for REST-ful routing that cares about verbs and urls.

Comment: I've had Clemens Vaster look at this, as well as some of his members of his team.  I'm pretty sure they know what the issue is, but the technical complexities of altering the message, at this level (where it does not know what type of message it is), cause the problem when it unwraps it at a higher level.  I'm sure it's very complicated, and you have to know the nuances of WCF beyond which I'm at.  Still it was a great learning exercise that I'm still pursuing, although not as diligently.  When I have time, I still dig into it.

Comment: The solution is to feed the relay into a reverse proxy, so that once it's past the firewall, it can be routed within it.  What I'm trying to do is just that, using Fiddler as the reverse router, as well as the hosting container for the relay service.  See Twiddler at itbatman.com